# Cannot change Azure tier using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I am the database owner on my Azure Database and I confirmed that using SELECT IS_MEMBER('db_owner') (returns 1)
When I try to run the command:

```
ALTER DATABASE [db] MODIFY (EDITION = 'standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S3');
```

it gives me the error as follows:

```
User does not have permission to alter database 'db', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
```

So I tried to grant myself the alter permissions on the database:

```
GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE:: db TO [USER_NAME]

Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
```

I dont know why I cant change the Azure Edition through script. I have done this through the Azure dashboard portal and it works just fine. But not through SSMS. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: sa has all the permissions already, and they can't be modified, so you can rule that out of the equation. Is the db name actually db? Is it in a state where it can be modified?

Comment: the db name is something different, but I just masked it

Comment: About state, it is live and running at the moment. I can query to it and it just works great except for this.

Comment: Is the user actually 'sa' or your user? What roles does the user have?

Comment: its actually my user. I just checked the permission_name property and it says I have GRANT CONNECT

Answer (score 1):

Go look at the documentation. Just because you are owner does not mean you can alter the database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-azure-sql-database

Comment: Ok. It says that I need to be added to the dbmanager role. I dont have that role on my sql server. How do I create one?

Comment: "Don't have it" and "can't see it" are different things. You said you could do this via the portal - so what identity is used in the portal? Did you try using the portal to assign your ID to this role?